# How to turn off and on DDP requests in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

What I'm trying to do is cache a meteor site in Cloudflare's CDN and have DDP requests go to another URL. I have that working, but what I want to do is make it so not a single DDP request is made until subscriptions actually require it. The public portion of the site is completely rendered with Fast Render, and cached by the CDN (until i purge it programmatically). Not until the user logs in is a single DDP request needed since all the info is embedded in the CDN cached page thanks to Fast Render.

The idea here I think is an important one: extremely popular public pages that don't change often (or ever) are cached by a CDN, without a single DDP request wasting resources until a user logs in, at which point there is no choice but to serve dynamic data over DDP (but also isn't resource intensive since only .01% of your visitors are signed up members).

So how can one take complete control of when DDP requests are made? Here's the typical first request that kicks off the process:

http://snapplr.com/e9vt

Arunoda from Meteor Hacks recommended the following

"Try disconnecting meteor connection before it's established. You can do it with:

Meteor.default_connection.disconnect()

Or you can override some methods of default_connection and force it to not send data. Try checking livedata_connection.js of livedata package. 
"

I tried the disconnect() thing but couldn't get it to work. Anyone have any more specific ideas of things to try?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Meteor.disconnect()](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_disconnect) is what you need. I notice now that you say you've tried it, but the signature of your function call doesn't match the latest docs. I'm not sure what the `default_connection` part of `Meteor.default_connection.disconnect()` comes from.

There is also a [stop()](http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_stop) function available on your subscriptions. It'd be a bit ugly if you needed to call that for each subscription just to achieve what you're asking for, so that seems unlikely but worth a try.

Comment: it's close, but I still can't block the first sockjs request: http://snapplr.com/2kcy ...i put the disconnect() code in the global scope, not in Meteor.startup(). Basically I need to find a way to stop it earlier on. Any ideas??

Comment: @faceyspacey.com i did some quick tries to get this working and no luck. i grepped the .meteor directory to see just where SockJS comes into play...i think you'll need to do some major surgery on the MeteorJS internals to get what you're after, tho I can't back that up with any facts. interesting question you posed, and I like where you're going with this.

Comment: i wonder if there is some overarching way to hi-jack all outgoing requests. I could then just weed out this request and silence it. Still not sure how I would apply this javascript before meteor's js is embedded in the page, but Arunoda's Fast Render does that.

Comment: a quick solution i just thought of is starting out with one DDP URL that pings some static CDN-cached bullshit URL, and then call disconnect(), and then change the DDP URL, and then reconnect when needed.

Comment: just tweeted this question, maybe one of the heavies will notice and swoop down with an answer for ya.

Comment: appreciate it brother.

Comment: So I did a quick test of starting off with an incorrect DDP url (i.e. one that will never hit my server) and then immediately disconnecting, and changing it in the correct URL, and then reconnecting and it worked: http://snapplr.com/3s93 ...the question is just whether all the data will properly be subscribed too if it didn't start off with a proper connection. I feel like there's a chance only new data could be sent to the client, but hopefully I'm wrong. ..If this works, you just have to pass a failing DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL from the command line, and then change it later in js.